# Page navigation performance in windows phone 7

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I have two pages, page1 and page2.In page2, there's a listbox which bind about 300 items.And when all items are loaded, I press the back key on phone to navigate to page1, and it takes a long time(about 1.2 seconds).Can anybody give me some advice to improve it?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to not add 300 items to a page at once.

If you want to show that many items in a list then the contents should be virtualized so they don't all have to be loaded.

How long doe "page1" take to open the first time? It may be that there's something happening there which causes the delay.

If you were able to provide a repro then we may be able to help more.